# How to link Salesforce1 feed page from a Lightning app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, visualforce

someone in Salesforce forum provided me with the following solution:
**return new PageReference('/one/one.app');**

It works when testing from my Salesforce sandbox, it doesn't when I do the same from my Salesforce1 sandbox.
This is part of VF page custom controller, and the VF force is the core of my lightning app. The error message I get is: 
"*You can't view this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices.*"

Is there a way to link in Salesforce1 the feed page, a little like is it possible in Salesforce to link the home page (entry to do that is: **return new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');** )

Thanks in advance for your help on this. 
Kind regards, 
Francesco

Comment: Are you building a component that is hosted as a tab in Salesforce1 mobile app?

Comment: Yes I am, Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Visualforce and only hosting this page in Salesforce1, you can use the `sforce.one` javascript object to navigate around. [You can read more in the dev guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm). But the general idea is that from your client side javascript, you want to call `sforce.one.navigateToFeed(userId,"NEWS")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christian! In the end I used something slightly differen but your suggestion put me on the right track! sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp");
Cheers, Francesco